# How to get the value from an object from args.getDataKeyValue

Tags: .net

Now suppose CompanyName is a object and I want to get one field's value from  args.getDataKeyValue("CompanyName"). Is this doable?

```
       function RowSelected(sender, args)
        {
            document.getElementById("<%= Label1.ClientID %>").innerHTML =
             "<b>CustomerID: </b>" + args.getDataKeyValue("CustomerID") +
             "<br />" +
             "<b>CompanyName: </b>" + args.getDataKeyValue("CompanyName");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can do it like this:

```
object companyName = args.getDataKeyValue("CompanyName");
Type companyNameType = companyName.GetType();
var companyNamePropValue = companyNameType.GetProperty("YourPropertyName").GetValue(companyName, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though this question is kind of old, the way I resolved this issue was by casting the KeyValue to the ObjectType.

```
CompanyName companyName = args.getDataKeyValue("CompanyName") as CompanyName;
```

Then you'll get all the properties from the KeyValue in the companyName object.